# IEnumPIDMap error-2 when running mingw32-make on opencv

Tags: opencv, cmake, mingw

I am following http://kevinhughes.ca/tutorials/opencv-install-on-windows-with-codeblocks-and-mingw/ but honestly I am so confused right now.

I am trying to compile the cmake files of opencv using mingw32-make commandline(last 2 lines of step-4 in the tutorial).

However, an error occurs at 37%. I have attached a screenshot below. Have any of you faced a similar problem.

I'm using:  opencv 3.0.0, window 8 - 64 bit, cmake 3.4.1

[image: Screenshot of mingw32-make cmd]

Comment: OpenCV 3.0 was already released. Don't try the alpha. Your problem could be a known and already fixed issue. I don't think it is a CMake issue.

Comment: I cross-checked with a readme file, and turns out it isn't the alpha version. I downloaded so many, so many times, I got confused. Thanks @usr1234567

Answer (score 0):

I figured the problem out(using my searching skills rather than my debugging skills)

Coincidentally, another question tackled the same error, but I wasn't able to find it when searching for a solution.
The link is: [OpenCV 3.0 videoio error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828740/opencv-3-0-videoio-error).
So thanks to [Neimsz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4483047/neimsz) for helping me indirectly!

I am reposting the solution incase someone searching for the same error gets stuck like I did.
 The problem was with cmake options.

In the "Cmake/OpenCVCompilerOptions.cmake" file, commenting the option

```
add_extra_compiler_option(-Werror=non-virtual-dtor)
```

and making it

```
#add_extra_compiler_option(-Werror=non-virtual-dtor)
```

and recompiling the same files using mingw32-make, worked just fine!