# Compilation of OpenCV 3.1.0 videoio error

Tags: opencv

Im trying to compile Opencv 3.1.0 with MingW 4.9.2 but i have the follow error

```
modules\videoio\CMakeFiles\opencv_videoio.dir\build.make:187: recipe for target
'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_dshow.cpp.obj' failed
mingw32-make[2]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/src/cap_dsho
w.cpp.obj] Error 1
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:4340: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_
videoio.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2

makefile:159: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I found that is a OpenCV build error during cap_dshow.cpp build. The solution showed [here](http://visp-doc.inria.fr/doxygen/visp-daily/tutorial-install-win81-mingw64.html) is no necessary because the file in Opencv 3.1 is already fixed.

During Cmake phase i've changed this (trough Cmake GUI 3.4.3), but doesnt work

```
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE = Debug
WITH_EIGEN = 0
WITH_OPENGL = 0
WITH_IPP = 0
WITH_QT = 1
```

I've tried the solution given in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27828740/opencv-3-0-videoio-error), but doesnt work neither

```
add_extra_compiler_option(-Werror=non-virtual-dtor)
```

My intention is work with C++, Opencv and the GUI designer of QT. I have installed the library qt-5.4.0-x64-mingw492r0-sjlj, it comes with its own MingW 4.9.2. 
(PS/for another proyect i've compiled Opencv3.1.0 with Mingw 4.9.3 and its works perfectly)

Can anybody helpme please!!!

Answer (score 3):

In file %OPENCV_HOME%\sources\modules\videoio\src\cap_dshow.cpp

Add in top:

```
#define STRSAFE_NO_DEPRECATE
```

Work for me in Qt 5.6.2, Mingw 4.9.2 OpenCV 3.2.0